# How to select A nodes that are in relation only to given B nodes or only their subsets

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have my graph looking like this

```
A1 -> B1 & B2 & B3
A2 -> B2 & B3
A3 -> B3
A4 -> B4
```

how in cypher can I ask for all A nodes that are in relation **only** to given B nodes **or only** their subsets ?

examples

```
A nodes for B1 & B2 & B3 & B4 would be [A1, A2, A3, A4]
A nodes for B1 & B2 & B3 would be [A1, A2, A3]
A nodes for B2 & B3 would be [A2, A3]
A nodes for B3 would be [A3] 
A nodes for B4 would be [A4]
A nodes for B1 & B2 would be []
A nodes for B2 would be []
```

Comment: Shouldn't A4 also be an applicable A node in your first example?

Comment: @cybersam thank you, You're right. Fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `B` nodes have a `name` property with values like "B1", "B2", etc., then this query should work (assuming that a `$list` parameter containing a list of B node name strings is passed):

```
MATCH (a:A)-->(b:B)
WITH a, COLLECT(b.name) AS bNames
WHERE ALL(n IN bNames WHERE n IN $list)
RETURN a;
```

Comment: There may be a quick way to optimize this by inserting this WHERE right after the MATCH: `WHERE b.name IN $list`. That way the only `a` to `b` patterns considered are this with the relevant :B nodes, and this could take advantage of an index on `:B(name)`.

Comment: @InverseFalcon could you paste your optimization also ?

Comment: @InverseFalcon I believe what is wanted is identification of the `A` nodes that are *only* connected to `B` nodes whose names are in the list. Your solution would not get most of the example results  in the question.

Comment: @cybersam I believe it would work. It does use all of your query, just adds an index lookup of the initial pattern based on the relevant :B node names from the list parameter.

Comment: Oh, OK. I thought you meant replacing the original `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Adding my answer, which builds on cybersam's answer but optimizes for index lookup (you'll need an index on `:B(name)` to take advantage of this)

```
MATCH (a:A)-->(b:B)
WHERE b.name in $list
WITH a, COLLECT(b.name) AS bNames
WHERE ALL(n IN bNames WHERE n IN $list)
RETURN a;
```

The advantage here is the WHERE clause in the second line will perform an index lookup of :B nodes and expand out to connected :A nodes. In other words, you get a much more relevant subset of nodes to consider immediately, rather than starting with all connected :A and :B nodes and filtering to the relevant :B nodes in `WHERE ALL()`, which won't use the index.

Try profiling both queries (after adding the index), you should see a reduction in db hits.